# Declaring scope for a bean

Tags: java, xml, spring, scope

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN //EN" http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="person" class = "org.dalai.listPers.Person"  scope = "singleton">                 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I think I am doing everything right, but anyway I get an error on line 4 :

> Attribute "scope" must be declared for element type "bean"

Any hints how to solve this would be appreciated

Comment: in spring by default scope is singleton, No need to give manually

Comment: @Pratik yes, but if I try to make it for exaple `prototype` I get the same error

Comment: Try this one.

<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope attribute is only supported in Spring 2.0, AND you have to be using the correct DTD/Schema.

you can refere below link for the same.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/22379-why-does-scope-attribute-cause-xml-parsing-exception

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this one, it depends on DTD Version.

In your case you are using default DTD so the define the scope is singleton="true" and if DTD is 2.0 so the scope of the version is scope="singleton"

DTD - Default

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN //EN" http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="person" class = "org.dalai.listPers.Person"  singleton="true">                 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

DTD - 2.0

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" 
    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="person" class = "org.dalai.listPers.Person" scope="singleton">
    </bean>
</beans>
```